# Facing challenges while editing table content in richtext box and formatting tr td and table tags

Tags: apex, html, ui, inputrichtext, sfdc-styleguide

i am havig a requirement where in reports needs to be generated with a data in structured format, i have used   and  tags to create a table with hidden borders, here the issue is that i was not able to edit the content in the table in rich text preview, here is my code

```
mailContent +='\n<span><table border="0" width="100%" class="reportTbl">';
    mailContent +='<tr><td width="20%"><span style="text-align:left;"> ID </span></td>';
    mailContent += '<td><span class="LabelTbl" style=""> &nbsp;'+NameID +'</span></td></tr>';
    
    mailContent +='<tr><td width="20%"><span style="text-align:left;">Name </span></td>';
    
    mailContent += '<td><span class="LabelTbl"> &nbsp;'+Name__c +'  '+Number__c+'</span></td></tr>';
    
    mailContent +='<tr><td width="20%"><span style="text-align:left;">Address</span></td>';
    mailContent += '<td><span class="LabelTbl"> &nbsp;'+student.Address+'</span></td></tr></table>';
```

i tried replacing table tags with div and span but the alignment isn't coming right, help me edit the table content in rich text or suggest some alternative ways to display the data in structured format and editable.